# 'invoke': no matching overloaded function found

Tags: c++, multithreading, std

Trying to make an organized "announcement" message-board with multi-threading.
One thread reads messages and calls the other thread to send said messages to connected users.

I'm not entirely sure why the std::thread constructor fails to compile. I've tried `ref()`ing everything, didn't work. I've tried `ref()`ing only the stuff that needs to be referenced, didn't work.

```
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>

namespace MenuVariables {
    std::set<std::string> usernames;
    std::queue<std::string> messages;
}

namespace MessageHandler {
    void readMessages(std::queue<std::string>& messages, std::string inputFile);
    void sendMessages(std::queue<std::string>& messages, std::set<std::string>& users, std::ofstream outputFile);
}

int main() {
    std::string inputFile = "data.txt";
    std::ofstream outputFile("output.txt");
    
    std::thread readThread(MessageHandler::readMessages, std::ref(MenuVariables::messages), inputFile);
    std::thread sendThread(MessageHandler::sendMessages, std::ref(MenuVariables::messages), std::ref(MenuVariables::usernames), outputFile);
    readThread.detach();
    sendThread.detach();
    return 0;
}
```

What shall I do?
The errors are:
[image: Errors]

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: does it compile with only the first call to thread ? ```thread readThread(MessageHandler::readMessages, ref(MenuVariables::messages), inputFile);``` ? it shoudn't change aniything but you can add ```&``` in front of ```MessageHandler```, check your include for set and queue and i don't see ```MenuVariables::usernames``` in your .h

Comment: My bad, copy pasted the wrong code. MenuVariables.h should now appear in the question.

Comment: It doesn't compile with writeThread being removed, but there's now a different symbol error: MenuVariable::messages already defined in MenuFunctions.obj

Comment: You are defining global variables in a header. Every source file that includes this header will get a definition, and then the linker would complain about multiple definitions. If you have to use global variables at all, declare them in the header with `extern` keyword, then define them in exactly one source file (without `extern`).

Comment: `sendMessages` takes `ofstream` by value, which would require copying it, but `ofstream` is not copyable. You are passing `ref(outputFile)` - that fails to compile because it doesn't match the signature of `sendMessages`.

Comment: Write thread doesn't compile because `sendMessages` is declared wrong, as I mentioned.

Comment: Cheers! Thank you. Please post your answer and I'll mark it as answered ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sendMessages` takes a `std::ofstream` by value, as `std::ofstream` is not copyable, even without `std::thread` you can only call it with a temporary or r value.

For example this won't compile:

```
MessageHandler::sendMessages(MenuVariables::messages, MenuVariables::usernames, outputFile);
```

but either of these will:

```
MessageHandler::sendMessages(MenuVariables::messages, MenuVariables::usernames, std::move(outputFile));
MessageHandler::sendMessages(MenuVariables::messages, MenuVariables::usernames, ofstream("output.txt"));
```

You therefore have the same options to make your `std::thread` constructor work:

```
thread sendThread(MessageHandler::sendMessages, ref(MenuVariables::messages), ref(MenuVariables::usernames), std::move(outputFile));
thread sendThread(MessageHandler::sendMessages, ref(MenuVariables::messages), ref(MenuVariables::usernames), ofstream("output.txt"));
```

Alternatively change `sendMessages` to take `outputFile` by reference:

```
void sendMessages(queue<string>& messages, set<string>& users, ofstream& outputFile);
```